# How to set the lookup field empty, or null

Tags: list

I'm creating a function to log all changes in a SharePoint list.

In fact I have a simple question: How to set a lookup field = NULL?

Comment: How are you tracking the changes? What all you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello Amal, Item[field] = new SPFieldLookupValue("")

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Comment: Is it a required field?

Comment: no, is not arequired field Amal

Comment: Try `Item[field] = null;'

Comment: I'll test some others solutions Amal because it doesnt works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("test");
                if (list != null)
                {
                    SPListItem li = list.AddItem();
                    li["Title"] = "Test NULL 2";
                    li["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now;
                    li["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now;
                    li["lookupcolumn"] = null;

                    li.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```